# Filter data with JSLink Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, jslink

I use JSLink to customize a SharePoint display list.

I managed to filter data as you can see in the following link:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91317/filter-out-items-in-list-view-using-jslink

When I click on the title of a column to try to filter a data second time, it systematically brings back all the old data instead of sorting out the previously filtered ones.

Answer (score 2):

In the provided example the filter is applied *by row index* and this is explains why different rows are displayed before and after sorting applied.

The below example demonstrates how to hide rows by *list item id*, in that case the filter will be applied consistently to the same rows:

```
(function () {

   function listPreRender(renderCtx) {

         var excludeItemIds = [1];  //hide list item with Id=1

         var rows = renderCtx.ListData.Row; //get current rows
         var filteredRows = rows.filter(function(row){
            var curItemId = parseInt(row.ID); 
            if(excludeItemIds.indexOf(curItemId) === -1)
                return row;                
         });

         renderCtx.ListData.Row = filteredRows;
         renderCtx.ListData.LastRow = filteredRows.length;  //update ListData.LastRow property
   }


    function registerListRenderer()
    {
      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
          Templates : {
            OnPreRender : listPreRender
          }
      });
    } 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');

})();
```

**Results**

Filtered list view

[image]

Filtered list view after applying sorting

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

My data are correctly filtered but the problem is after applying sorting or filter, like we can see in the screenshot :

http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=151851JSlink.png

The old data are always displayed… And the count is wrong too.